# Community registration page location

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, community-builder, self-registration

I am using the new Configurable self-register page for communities. But I would like to add some helpful text to the page. Does anyone know where I can find this page? [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_login_discovery_create_config_self.htm)

TheURL is baseURL/secur/CommunitiesSelfRegUi

Answer (score 1):

The CommunitiesSelfRegUi page generated by selecting 'Configurable Self-Reg Page' does not appear to be directly editable as it is not visible as a Lightning Component or Visualforce page. The Apex controlller that supports it is editable, but it will not include being able to display any messages other than errors.

To really configure the Self registration page it would be better to use a page modified using the community builder with the 'Community builder page' option.

The Lightning Registration page is editable via the Community Builder like the other pages within a lightning community now.

Go to Setup>All Communities>Builder for the specific community and then select the Register page.

[image]

You can then drag and drop in additional elements such as Rich Text or HTML where you can add content. You can also customise all the landing page elements such as logo, colours, etc for the individual site look and feel that is required.

[image]

Comment: Hi Dave, that's for the normal rego page. The one I'm working with isn't affected by this one.

Comment: Ah, I think I have found it. Just testing something now.

Comment: I know it's been awhile, but did you find anyway to edit the /secur/CommunitiesSelfRegUi ?

Comment: Hi DCole, Did you find the solution to update the CommunitiesSelfRegUi page ?